# Execution order of windows in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

**Background**

I've got a spark streaming application, that reads data from Kinesis -> does the windowing on it -> saves the data to external system (by doing foreachRDD).

Recently I've observed, that my windows are consumed by foreachRDD one-by-one. This means if I have sudden burst of data in my app (so that foreachRDD for a window takes a long time), then the windows will be stacking in a queue before being processed (while most of machines in my cluster are idle).

**Question**

Is this a semantic of spark streaming that windows are being processed one-by-one? If yes, is there any way to do "windowing" operation in parallel in spark, so that windows are consumed by foreachRDD at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Find out how many shards your kinesis stream has and create that many receivers by invoking createStream defined in the KinesisUtils Scala class.

This [blog post from Amazon](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx2MQREB43K3BFK/Optimize-Spark-Streaming-to-Efficiently-Process-Amazon-Kinesis-Streams) explains it well ....

> Every input DStream is associated with a receiver, and in this case
>   also with a KCL worker. The best way to understand this is to refer to
>   the method createStream defined in the KinesisUtils Scala class.
>
> Every call to KinesisUtils.createStream instantiates a Spark Streaming
>   receiver and a KCL worker process on a Spark executor. The first time
>   a KCL worker is created, it connects to the Amazon Kinesis stream and
>   instantiates a record processor for every shard that it manages. For
>   every subsequent call, a new KCL worker is created and the record
>   processors are re-balanced among all available KCL workers. The KCL
>   workers pull data from the shards, and routes them to the receiver,
>   which in turns stores them into the associated DStream.